# Display most recent release (v*) tag(s)

Tags: git

#### What I want

A way to see the most recent release tag(s).

#### What I've tried

I went down a short path on `git describe` but I couldn't find how to make it work on all refs (get tags from all branches). I also briefly looked at `show-refs`, `for-each-ref` & `rev-list` but couldn't quite get it to do what I wanted.

Currently I use this to list out all tags starting on `v` and sort them in descending order, based on refname:

```
git tag -l v* --sort=-v:refname
```

which gives an output looking like

```
v2.0.32
v2.0.31
v2.0.29
v2.0.28
v2.0.27
v2.0.26
v2.0.25
v2.0.24
v2.0.23
v2.0.22
v2.0.21
v2.0.20
v2.0.19
v2.0.18
...
```

which is all good, except it's too much. I'd like to use some of limiter argument but I can't seem to find anything to limit the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

So I found the solution while writing this question:

```
git tag -l 'v*' --sort=-v:refname | sed -n 1,5p
```

The piped `sed` command will print only lines 1 through 5.
I had this aliased under `git v` as `git config alias "tag -l 'v*' --sort=-v:refname | sed -n 1,5p"` which has be changed to

```
git config alias.v "! git tag -l 'v*' --sort=-v:refname | sed -n 1,5p"
```

Note the `!` in front, which tells git to interpret it as an external command (which is why we also add the `git`, which you usually don't start your git aliases with) which allows us to pipe stuff, instead of doing just doing git commands.

---

Edit, from @LeGEC in the comments below:
Instead of `sed -n 1,5p` you can use

```
head -5
```

to specify the range, which is arguably more intuitive.

Comment: It's a good idea to quote the pattern, e.g., `-l 'v*'`. Otherwise the shell will replace `v*` with each current-directory file whose name starts with `v`. When there are no such files, most shells leave `v*` to Git, which then handles the `*` the way you want, so this command works *until* you enter a directory with files `viaduct.py` and `victory.txt`, and then it suddenly stops working, very mysteriously.

Comment: Oh, great addition! I edited the answer with it. Thanks

Comment: `head -5` will give you the same result than `sed -n 1,5p`, and be more explicit IMHO

Comment: Yes, I like that a lot more. I'm not sure how `head -5` works though? Is it a command you only use piped with git commands to specifcy head ranges?

I added it to the answer. Thanks for the great addition/correction/enhancement.